# MCP3008 returns sinusoidal values

Tags: python, electronics, spi

Alright, I have to start off with the fact I'm a n00b. So there's a good chance I'm screwing something up.

I've got an MCP3008 10-bit ADC hooked up to my Raspberry Pi B+ via a Cobbler.

Here are the particulars of my kernel:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 3.18.11+ #781 PREEMPT Tue Apr 21 18:02:18 BST 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

I've wired up the default SPI0_SCLK, MISO, MOSI, and CE0_N to the MCP3008. I roughly followed [raspberrypi-spy's guidlines](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/10/analogue-sensors-on-the-raspberry-pi-using-an-mcp3008/), but making appropriate adaptations for the B+ rather than their A.

I enabled SPI via raspi-config and confirm /dev/spidev0.0 and /dev/spidev/0.1 exist. I also ensured I have the spi_bcm2708 driver enabled.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ll /dev/spidev0.*
crw-rw---T 1 root spi 153, 1 Jan  1  1970 /dev/spidev0.1
crw-rw---T 1 root spi 153, 0 Jan  1  1970 /dev/spidev0.0
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
ctr                     3993  1 
ccm                     8238  1 
snd_bcm2835            21149  0 
snd_pcm                90778  1 snd_bcm2835
snd_seq                61097  0 
snd_seq_device          7209  1 snd_seq
snd_timer              23007  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    66325  5 snd_bcm2835,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_seq_device
arc4                    1964  2 
rt2800usb              18958  0 
rt2800lib              81833  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00usb              11926  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              47785  3 rt2x00usb,rt2800lib,rt2800usb
mac80211              552848  3 rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb,rt2800lib
spi_bcm2708             6018  0 
i2c_bcm2708             6200  0 
cfg80211              462846  2 mac80211,rt2x00lib
crc_ccitt               1612  1 rt2800lib
rfkill                 22347  2 cfg80211
uio_pdrv_genirq         3666  0 
uio                     9897  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
```

Just to add more information, but `/boot/config.txt`

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ cat /boot/config.txt 
# For more options and information see 
# http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
#disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

dtparam=spi=on
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtoverlay=spi-bcm2835-overlay
dtoverlay=spi-bcm2708-overlay
```

I'm using the python py-spidev. I cannot recall where I installed it from, but I did find this in the .egg:

```
Metadata-Version: 1.1
Name: spidev
Version: 3.0
Summary: Python bindings for Linux SPI access through spidev
Home-page: http://github.com/doceme/py-spidev
Author: Stephen Caudle
Author-email: scaudle@doceme.com
License: GPLv2
Description: Python Spidev
```

I have nothing connected to the 8 MCP3008's ADC inputs, so I should get something like 0, or close there abouts. My code is pretty easy. I borrowed the `ReadChannel` function from the aforementioned raspberrypi-spy link. I assume that is fairly robust.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ cat adctest.py 
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import spidev

# Open SPI bus
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,0)


####################################################################################
# Function to read SPI data from MCP3008 chip
# Channel must be an integer 0-7
def ReadChannel(channel):
  adc  = spi.xfer2([1,(8+channel)<<4,0])
  data = ((adc[1]&3) << 8) + adc[2]
  return data

####################################################################################

fmt= '{0:5d}'
while True:
   chans = [0]*8
   for t in range(8):
      chans[t] = ReadChannel(t)
      #time.sleep(0.01)
   line = []
   for chan in chans:
      line.append(fmt.format(chan))
   print ' '.join(line)
   time.sleep(0.25)
```

The resultant output is a little perplexing:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo ./adctest.py 
   21    30     0    13     7    17     2     0
    0     7     0     6     5    17     6     7
   41    40    39    49    57    71    87   126
   72    54    46    48    53    60    76   110
   58    30    13     8     0     0     0     0
    0     0     0     3     1     6     0     0
   11     7     4    13    16    30    39    68
   65    48    48    50    54    64    79   125
   73    52    47    47    54    59    73   105
   57    42    29    27    24    20    22    21
    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    0     4     0     4     4     6     3     4
   12    11     8    21    24    32    43    80
   69    55    48    50    56    67    81   125
   73    50    42    46    51    56    72   106
   53    34    20    21    18    14    16     7
    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
    1     4     2     5     4     7     3     7
   16    16    18    25    34    44    57    94
   73    54    48    53    61    65    84   123
   69    51    41    44    48    55    68    96
```

I connected a device to one channel and I get the exact same thing. I reconnected that ADC channel to GND and I get the same sinusoidal behavior. Same issue if I connect a channel to +3.3VDC. I've swapped out the MCP3008 and I get the same response.

The SPI driver on my pi appears to function correctly. I disconnected my circuit, and tied MOSI to MISO and ran the loopback test, mentioned on [raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#spi-overview). This appears to work correctly.

I'm completely perplexed. I had this all functioning a few weeks ago. Maybe something in a recent `apt-get upgrade` broke things. Any adivce would be most helpful.

Thanks a million,
~Rich

Answer (score 3):

OMG. After staring at this for hours, I finally figured it out.

Looks like in my haste of breaking apart my breadboard and recabling a more basic circuit I inadvertently removed the wires tying GND and 3.3VDC from one side of the board to the other. Thus, when I tested the ADC against GND and +3VDC, I was not connecting them to anything.

So, in summary, the MCP3008 returns a sinusoidal signal if the pin is floating. I solved it myself!

Any way, I guess posting a plea for help got me thinking more. Thanks anyway. Hope this post helps people the future.

~Rich

Comment: I have the exact same problem as you. I have checked every connection multiple times and there is no way they are wrong. I'm getting sine wave as output. If I connect +3VDC with any resistance to any of sensor pins then it goes straight to 1023.